# Swift returns 'UInt32' is not convertible to 'CGImage'

Tags: ios, swift

I got this error message based on code below:

Error message

```
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/XXXXX/HAHA.swift:534:38: 'UInt32' is not convertible to 'CGImage'
```

My code

```
let context : CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage), CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage),
                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage),
                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image.CGImage),
                CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(UInt32(image.CGImage)).rawValue)!;

            CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error states you are passing a `UInt32` to a function which expects a `CGImage`.

[CGImageGetBitmapInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageGetBitmapInfo) expects a `CGImage` as it's argument and returns `CGBitmapInfo`

You are probably looking for:

```
UInt32(CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage).rawValue)
```

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: Still you are using the old way, did you changed that code as mentioned in my answer ?

Comment: I got this error message, 'UInt32' is not convertible to 'CGBitmapInfo'

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Remove that UInt32 conversion from above code

Comment: I got 'UInt32' is not convertible to 'CGImage'.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as the error states, you can't convert a number to a `CGImage`

I'm not sure why you're trying to convert a `CGImage` into a `UInt32` before passing it into `CGImageGetBitmapInfo`. Just pass the `CGImage` in directly.

```
CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage);
```

Comment: I got  'UInt32' is not convertible to 'CGBitmapInfo'.

Answer (score 1):

Raw value is returning UInt32 so try:

```
CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage).rawValue
```